# Potential security vulnerabilities in a ticketing implementation

Tags: security, authentication, passwords, privacy, brute-force

I'm trying to brainstorm potential security vulnerabilities for this scenario (btw, I've asked a related question [several days ago](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192872/using-a-simple-5-character-pass-for-event-vs-qr-barcode), however, from the answers, I've realized that explaining the EXACT scenario is extremely crucial, because many of the answers were (a bit) irrelevant due to this. I've also included vulnerabilities I've identified so far, and how to mitigate them, so feedback on them would be appreciated. So here we go:

a) The whole system will be a "ticketing" system, but not an ordinary ticket, but a "pass" system. Meaning: A customer goes and orders a "pass" ticket, which gives him access to certain perks at certain places (like free entrance to museums) for a SPECIFIC period of time. Meaning, it's a ticket that EXPIRES after 1-7 days (but no more than 7 days).

b) The "flow" of the user is:

1. User goes to the website, orders a ticket for a specific period of time, which gives him perks at certain locations (museums etc.)
2. After a successful order, the website prints a 6-letter-long string (an ID). Example: `GFZ-GFY`. There are 26^6 (~308 million) potential combinations. Of course, these IDs will be stored in a secure database.
3. User then goes to the museum (or other venue) and shows the 6-letter-long string. The employee checks its validity with a web-app  or sending an SMS to a number, getting the validity status immediately (in both cases, the code will query against the database to check for the ticket validity).

So far, I've identified 2 potential issues:

a) Brute-force attacks

There will be 2 "attack surfaces" under which this can occur:

1. A museum employee will have a gated access to the web-app (to verify ticket validity). The way I mitigate this is limiting the # of look-ups to 1,000 a day per-user-account.
2. A user will be able to check the status of his order. I'll mitigate this in several ways: first, the URL not be "public", and available only to users who purchased the ticket. Second, I'll implement [ReCaptcha v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3), IP bans on more than 10 unsuccessful requests per hour.
3. The # of "active" tickets at a time is expected to be 5000 (at its peak), normal would be something like 500-1000, so considering there are hundreds of millions of combinations, it would take a significant effort for an attacker to brute-force the way through this.

The second (and easier) approach an attacker could take is simply buying a ticket and re-publishing it, or publishing it online for anyone to use. The way I'll mitigate this is by:

1. After a museum checks the validity of the pass, if they check it again, there will be a notification saying: This pass has been checked at this place at this time: [time-date].
2. While I do plan on re-using the same code, I'll make sure there is a period of minimum 90 days between periods. Maybe there's some vulnerability of doing this that I'm not aware of. The code MAY or MAY not be used again after 90 days passed after its "expiration" date. All I'm saying is that it will be released in the "pool" of potential (300+ million) codes that could be used. Maybe this is not such a good idea?
3. The customer will be given (sent to an address, or instructed to pick-up), a blank card-like "ticket" where the code will be written on it (or he'll have to write the code with a pen on the ticket). This will make an attack harder to do, since the attacker would now need to have access BOTH to the code + a printer that could print such cards with the same material.

Do you see any other potential attack that could be done? Is there anything I'm missing at my current mitigation approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I would also plan for the case that your database is compromised, e.g. through SQL-injection. Instead of storing the codes plain text, you can use any decent password-hash function and store only the hash of the code. The verification procedure is the same as with passwords.

If there is no user id, the code must be retrievable with a database query, then you cannot use salting. In this case we can use a key derivation function (KDF), which needs some time to calculate a hash to make brute-forcing harder. The missing salt leads to the next point:

I would feel more comfortable using longer codes. If I read the table correctly, the probability to find a valid code with your setup (~28bit / 3000 active codes) is about 0.001 because of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Codes with 9 characters are probably a good compromise, since they are case insensitive they can still be typed fast, but allow for 5E12 combinations. Such codes could be left in the database, so one can tell that a ticket has expired, there is no need to re-use them. Brute-forcing 3 million hashes is no big obstacle even with a KDF, brute-forcing with 5E12 combinations is much more of a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure with protecting every possible entry with Google Recaptcha set on a "high" level, that such brute force is possible.

Comment: @anemaria20 - Brute-forcing is not done online on the website, it can be applied offline when the attacker already knows the content of the database (Recaptcha is no protection). Maybe you want to have a look at my demo about [SQL-injection](https://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/hash_sqlinjection.php), then you can decide whether this could be a threat or not. If you always use prepared statements and have no external libraries, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have spent a decent amount of time considering this and you have identified your largest potential attack surfaces.

Martinstoeckli identifies what I would have considered the next greatest issues by raising the potential of SQL injection and brute force.  In my experience the best mitigation to SQL injection is just going to be to make sure that all input is properly sanitized.  The brute force issue can never be fully solved and a 6 character key is somewhat easy to crack.  Including the use of a KDF would seem like a good idea but you also have to consider what the performance impact on your database will be.  With an estimated 500-1000 users/keys i don't think that it would be a huge concern.

I would recommend not reusing keys because depending on how they are stored that could lead to hash collision attacks after a time depending on the specifics of how they are stored.

After those issues I would actually recommend looking into the specifics of how you are hosting this application.  Is it hosted on a physical server that you have access to or is it a VM sitting somewhere in the cloud?  Each of those is going to have its own risks.